# Get name of all files from a directory and do a "for" with them

Tags: php

I have a php code that reads an encrypted file and decrypts it. What is a whole mass? That is, there is a folder that will only have 4/5 encrypted files and I want to decrypt all, preferably for a win rar.

```
<?php

$file= "text.txt";

    $decrypted = decrypt_file($file,'pass');
    header('Content-type:application/txt');
    fpassthru($decrypted);

function decrypt_file($file,$passphrase){
    $iv = substr(md5("\x18\x3C\x58".$passphrase,true),0,8);
    $key = substr(md5("\x2D\xFC\xD8".$passphrase,true).md5("\x2D\xFC\xD8".$passphrase,true),0,24);
    $opts = array('iv'=>$iv, 'key'=>$key);
    $fp = fopen($file,'rb');
    stream_filter_append($fp, 'mdecrypt.tripledes', STREAM_FILTER_READ, $opts);
    return $fp;
  }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`glob()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) function does just that. And to make a zip file you can use [`ZipArchive`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php) too. Here's an exmaple:

```
<?php
// create a zip file
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$res = $zip->open('test.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE);

$directory = 'path/to/folder';
foreach (glob("$directory/*.txt") as $filename) {
    // get the decrypted content
    $decrypted = decrypt_file($filename,'pass');

    // add it to the zip
    $zip->addFromString($filename, $decrypted);
}

$zip->close();

header("Location: test.zip");
```

So we loop over each file, decrypt it and add that text to the zip as its own file with the same filename. When we're finished, we're left with `test.zip` in this example, so we redirect the user towards that file to download it. You could instead output the correct content-type and associated headers for the zip instead. Also note that you may need to sort out permissions for saving test.zip, and look at the `ZipArchive`'s `open` method to provide the correct flags for overwriting. Good luck!

Comment: I tried it this way but when I tried to decrypt, I only downloaded 1 file even though they are 3 in the folder

Comment: Are you saying you want to download all the files as a zip?

Comment: I've updated my answer to show how all the files can be added to a single zip file and downloaded after being decrypted.

Comment: That was exactly what I wanted. But I'm getting an error "Warning: ZipArchive :: addFromString () expects parameter 2 to be string, resource" anyone know how I can solve?

Comment: Ah sorry yes, you're returning a file pointer. You need to return a string. You could do something like `return stream_get_contents($fp)` or just save the files first then read them again to zip.